# How to set access grant for oauth2_client?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, pycharm, boto, oauth2client

I am new to Boto and Google Cloud Storage and am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary).

I am experiencing two problems:

1) When running the file from command line

```
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
# URI scheme for accessing local files.
LOCAL_FILE = 'file'

# Fallback logic. In https://console.developers.google.com
# under Credentials, create a new client ID for an installed application.
# Required only if you have not configured client ID/secret in
# the .boto file or as environment variables.
CLIENT_ID = 'your client id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your client secret'
gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

now = time.time()
CATS_BUCKET = 'cats-%d' % now
DOGS_BUCKET = 'dogs-%d' % now

# Your project ID can be found at https://console.developers.google.com/
# If there is no domain for your project, then project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT'
project_id = 'ixxx-prod'

for name in (CATS_BUCKET, DOGS_BUCKET):
    # Instantiate a BucketStorageUri object.
    uri = boto.storage_uri(name, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
    # Try to create the bucket.
    try:
        # If the default project is defined,
        # you do not need the headers.
        # Just call: uri.create_bucket()
        header_values = {"x-goog-project-id": project_id}
        uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)
```

It throws an exception right at `create_bucket`:

> oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

I am not sure how to proceed here, considering the `.boto` file exists in my home folder.

2) The other problem is the moment I run the same script within PyCharm, it crashes at importing gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
```

> ImportError: cannot import name HAS_CRYPTO

Within `oauth2_client.py` there is the line

```
from oauth2client.client import HAS_CRYPTO
```

and this one seems to throw an exception. This doesn't seem to happen within the command line.

Both command line and PyCharm are using the same Virtual-env, so it's a mystery to me why it behaves differently. If you have any idea, please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in PyCharm (4.0.3).

The only thing I can think of is to rerun: `gcloud auth login`